# Replace hour and minutes in pandas timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

**Problem:** I have the following pandas dataframe. Based on some_time I want to replace the hour and minute with t_hour and t_min such that I obtain target_time.

```
  some_time                    target_time                    t_hour       t_min
0 2020-09-01 19:00:58.0000     2020-09-01 20:00:00.0000       20           00
1 2020-10-31 14:44:00.0000     2020-10-31 17:45:00.0000       17           45
```

**Attempts**:

```
data['target_time'] = data['start_time'].replace(hour=data['t_hour'],minute=data['t_min'], second=0))
```

which did not work out

Error:

```
TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hour'
```

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a built-in, "vectorized" option to access the replace method of the timestamps. You'll have to go with an iterative solution I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the freedom to make the example more illustrative; given a dataframe like

```
data
           start_time target_time  t_hour  t_min
0 2020-09-01 19:00:58  2020-09-01      20      0
1 2020-10-31 14:44:00  2020-10-31      17     45
```

first make sure that datetime columns are all converted to dtype datetime[64]. Then you can apply a custom function to achieve your goal, e.g.

```
def insert_time(row):
    return row['start_time'].replace(hour=row['t_hour'], minute=row['t_min'], second=0)

data['target_time'] = data.apply(lambda r: insert_time(r), axis=1)
```

This will give you

```
data
           start_time         target_time  t_hour  t_min
0 2020-09-01 19:00:58 2020-09-01 20:00:00      20      0
1 2020-10-31 14:44:00 2020-10-31 17:45:00      17     45
```

Comment: btw. a "vectorized" approach would be to floor the datetime to the day (`.dt.floor("d")`), then add hour/minute as a timedelta.